# Parse DateTime from Dropdown Selected Value

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting date from a dropdown. The date format that is coming in **weekStartDate** is **12/05/2014 12:00:00 AM**. I want it to be as **2014/05/12  12:00:00 AM**

```
DateTime weekStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DrpDwnGetPayPeriod.SelectedValue);
```

The dropdown has values as 05 May 2014 , 12 May 2014 . When I try to parse it , I get error as String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
I tried following:

```
DateTime weekStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DrpDwnGetPayPeriod.SelectedValue, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Dateformatting is for output only - DateTime is just DateTime :-)

Comment: Are you getting back a `string` or a `DateTime`?  What type do you want the end result to be?

Comment: @MortenAnderson Date formatting is also for parsing (input). Not just output.

Comment: @mason your correct - I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The dropdown has values as 05 May 2014 , 12 May 2014 . When I try to
>   parse it , I get error as String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime

So these are entries in the `DropDownList`:

```
05 May 2014
12 May 2014
21 Apr 2014
```

and you want to parse it to a real `DateTime`.

Then you can use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
// presuming "21 Apr 2014" is DrpDwnGetPayPeriod.SelectedValue
DateTime weekStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact("21 Apr 2014", "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Since you're using three letter abbreviations for month names you need to use `MMM`.

MSDN: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: did work.. but still one issue... if it is '21 Apr 2014' , doesn't work.  I am using first three letters in drop down.

Comment: @user3590485: then you need `MMM` for months, i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Click this link for custom date time formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

I think you have to use a function like this:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("YY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS TT")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear in your question. But I'm going to assume you want to know "how do I convert a string in a certain format into a DateTime object?" If that's not your question, please clarify and realize that you need to make your question clearer in the beginning.

Learn to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And use the [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That gives us...

```
DateTime weekStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DrpDwnGetPayPeriod.SelectedValue, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Note, you may want to make use of `DateTime.TryParseExact`. That will allow you to handle values that don't match the specified format.

Comment: @Dunken you have to make absolutely sure the date in the DrpDwnGetPayPeriod are in the expected format. They might depend on the regional settings regarding the way you populate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard format `"G"`:

```
weekStartDate.ToString("G"); //G: 12/5/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to change the formatting on weekStartDate? You would just need to do something along these lines:

```
weekStartDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt");
```

[Here's an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RT6hsp).